# Does Linux support standalone package / software's that not require installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, portable-applications

In my work, I have got a Windows Laptop with limited access, I can't install anything because admin privilege required but lucky this website `https://portableapps.com/apps` have many apps that can be run without installation and admin not required even there is a portable MySQL ,Apache server etc.

Now I have got access to an old Ubuntu server without internet and no `sudo` privilage with the below details:-

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
```

I want to run the `screen` command but it's not installed and I have no privilege plus it's not connected to the internet . is there a way to run this package `screen` in a portable/standalone way same like Windows OS? is there a way to convert any Linux package to standalone package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, package managers like ubuntu's [`apt`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt) require internet access to pull the source and package info from mirrors, and install the package. Ubuntu does also have [Personal Package Archive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA) (PPA), but those will also require internet access for at least the first step of downloading the source and package info. You would also need to have root privileges to use these package managers and PPAs.

The only real option is to download the source of the command from [`gnu`](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=screen) on another machine with internet access (your windows machine would be fine), store on an external drive, move to the linux machine, and and build the tool from source code you get there.

Once built you can then add the binary to a location you have access to which is on the PATH, or add the binary location to the PATH.

Comment: I feel there is hope with your solution ...how to download the `screen` command from GNU ?

Comment: I included the wrong link, sorry! You can access it [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=screen), and the answer is updated with the proper link

Comment: thanks, I will try and learn how to build it and see how it works.

Comment: I believe all gnu projects are built using a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) and the [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) tool (also developed by gnu)

Comment: the build should be done on the server machine? or any other Linux machine then copy it to the server?

Comment: You should build it on the machine you indent to use it on. Programs can be compiled differently based on the machine's OS and hardware, so its always safer to built it where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should be able to manually install programs into your home directory and run them from there.

There are a few caveats:

- You **cannot** use the system's package manager, it requires root access.
- You will have to manually install the software into your home directory.
- If the program requires elevated privilege (root), it still won't work.
- Ubuntu's security policies (AppArmor) may still block you.
- Your company may have some other non-standard access controls in place that will block you.